# Can NHibernate create tables from existing classes automatically?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm very new at this, but I need to create new tables from existing classes without creating them by hand. Can this be done using a tool or command line?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, with nhibernate you can generate and update schemas automatically.

```
var cfg = new Configuration();  
cfg.Configure();  
cfg.AddAssembly(typeof (aClassFromYourProject).Assembly);  
new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(false, true, false, false);
```

Update: The overload options for SchemaExport.Execute have changed in the 3.x versions. The last argument is no longer needed.

```
new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(true, true, false);
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do it without clearing all current data?